# Which mechanism is a better way to extend Dictionary to deal with missing keys and why?

Tags: c#, dictionary, extension-methods, keynotfoundexception

There is a minor annoyance I find myself with a lot - I have a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` that contains values that may or may not be there.

So normal behaviour would be to use the indexer, like this:

```
object result = myDictionary["key"];
```

However, if `"key"` is not in the dictionary this throws a `KeyNotFoundException`, so you do this instead:

```
object val;
if (!myDictionary.TryGetValue("key", out val))
{
    val = ifNotFound;
}
```

Which is fine, except that I can have a load of these in a row - `TryGetValue` starts to feel awful clunky.

So option 1 is an extension method:

```
public static TValue TryGet<TKey, TValue>(
    this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> input, 
    TKey key, 
    TValue ifNotFound = default(TValue))
{
    TValue val;
    if (input.TryGetValue(key, out val))
    {
        return val;
    }

    return ifNotFound;
}
```

Which lets me do:

```
object result = myDictionary.TryGet("key1") ?? ifNotFound;

int i = anotherDictionary.TryGet("key2", -1);
```

Which is simple enough, but an additional extension method with a name similar to existing instance methods potentially adds confusion and reduces maintainability. It's also not consistent with the dictionary's indexer set - that will handle missing keys.

So option 2 is a new implementation of `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` with a implicit cast from `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` but an indexer that returns `default(TValue)` instead of throwing a `KeyNotFoundException`.

That let's me do:

```
ForgivingDictionary<string, object> dict = myDictionary;

object val = dict["key"] ?? ifNotFound;

// do stuff to val, then...
dict["key"] = val;
```

So now the get and set values are consistent, but value types are messier and `ForgivingDictionary` involves a lot more code.

Both methods seem 'messy' - is there a better way to do this already in .Net?

Both methods make compromises that could cause confusion, but is one more obvious/clear than the other? And why?

Comment: Well, as far as I understand, you need just better name for your extension method, may be more specific - ex. SafeGetValue, GetOrUseValue, etc. Extension methods are quite common even in framework classes, so I guess you shouldn't be affraid of them.

Comment: IMO that extension method doesn't cause confusion and has the big advantage to be applicable to all dictionaries.

Comment: the `myDictionary.TryGet("key1") ?? ifNotFound;` syntax will only work for reference objects right?

Comment: Of course, if your dictionary values are ints, doubles, decimals, etc., default(TValue) is going to return 0, and you'd have no way of discerning between a legitimate 0 that is associated with a key and a default 0 that comes back because the key doesn't exist. There is a place and a time to use the `bool ContainsKey(string key)` method.

Comment: @Magnus yeah, `myDictionary.TryGet("key2", valueIfNotFound)` will work for value types, or you can do `myDictionary.TryGet("key2")` and get the default for the value type.

Comment: IMHO, the 'Try' prefix should be used exclusively with methods that take in at least one out parameter and returns a bool, to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Jay - yes, I'd still expect to use `TryGetValue` sometimes, for instance if the way to get a value if the dictionary value is missing is expensive.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254178/c-sharp-dictionaries-valueornull-valueordefault

Comment: @nawfal yeah, though that's a simpler problem - I already know that `TryGetValue` is better than `x.ContainsKey(key) ? x[key] : something` and I was wondering about the best way of simplifying the call to `TryGetValue`. The answer to their question is kind of the starting point for mine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When naming an extension method intended to replace an existing method, I tend to add to the method name for specificity rather than shortening it:

```
GetValueOrDefault(...)
```

As for the `ForgivingDictionary`, you can constrain `TKey` so that it can't be a value type. However, if you must deal with value types in it, you're going to return something for a value type and the best option is to return `default(TKey)` since you can't return `null`.

Honestly, I'd go with the extension method.

**Edit**: `GetValueOrDefault()`, of course, wouldn't add to the dictionary if it didn't find the key. I would just return a default value if it wasn't found, because that's how it's named. If one wanted it to insert as well, a good name would be `GetValueOrInsertDefault()`.

Comment: I would do the extension method as well, and use the same name. With intellisense and autocomplete, having a slightly longer name like that is hardly noticeable. :) A method's name should be clear and help identify what it does without needing to look it up.

Comment: Fair enough - it seems the consensus is that the extension method's best but use a more descriptive name.

Comment: The extension method doesn't add to the dictionary though, it just wraps `TryGetValue`

Comment: @Keith: Yeah, that didn't come out right. I rephrased it. I had added that bit on from recently doing something similar myself, to make populating dictionaries a bit easier (specifically, `Dictionary<T,List<U>>`-style population).

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to infer from your question what should be done when a key is not found. I can imagine nothing should be done in that case, but I can also imagine the opposite.
Anyway, an elegant alternative for a series of these TryGetValue-statements you describe, is using one of the following extension methods. I have provided two options, depending on whether something should be done or not when the dictionary does not contain the key:

```
/// <summary> Iterates over all values corresponding to the specified keys, 
///for which the key is found in the dictionary. </summary>
public static IEnumerable<TValue> TryGetValues<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, IEnumerable<TKey> keys)
{
    TValue value;
    foreach (TKey key in keys)
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
            yield return value;
}

/// <summary> Iterates over all values corresponding to the specified keys, 
///for which the key is found in the dictionary. A function can be specified to handle not finding a key. </summary>
public static IEnumerable<TValue> TryGetValues<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, IEnumerable<TKey> keys, Action<TKey> notFoundHandler)
{
    TValue value;
    foreach (TKey key in keys)
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
            yield return value;
        else
            notFoundHandler(key);                        
}
```

Example code on how to use this is:

```
TKey[] keys = new TKey{...};
foreach(TValue value in dictionary.TryGetValues(keys))
{
    //some action on all values here
}
```

Comment: When a key is not found it returns `default(TValue)`, which will be `null` for a reference type and the default for a value type (`0` for an `int` and so on). I'm not sure your `TryGetValues` method does what I need - I think in that circumstance I might use a Linq `join` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Or perhaps

```
public static TValue TryGet<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> input, 
                                                   TKey key)
{

     return input.ContainsKey(key) ? input[key] : *some default value*;

}
```

Comment: That requires two explicit lookups, whereas the OP's method only requires one, so IMHO is not as optimal.

Comment: @Mikey Cee has it right `dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out val)` is quicker than `dictionary.ContainsKey(key) ? input[key] : default`. My method also used [`default(TValue)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d(v=vs.80).aspx) or an optional value to use if the key isn't found.