# Dictionary extension compiles but not callable

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am doing the exact same thing as mentioned here:[Which mechanism is a better way to extend Dictionary to deal with missing keys and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214975/which-mechanism-is-a-better-way-to-extend-dictionary-to-deal-with-missing-keys-a)

Making a getter to a dictionary that returns a default. It compiles just fine but anyone trying to use it gets a compiler error saying … and no extension method 'ObjectForKey' accepting a first argument of type System.collections.Genericc.Dictionary could be found.

Here is the definition

```
public static TValue ObjectForKey<TKey,TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey,TValue> dictionary, TKey key)
{
    TValue val = default(TValue);
    dictionary.TryGetValue(key,out val);
    return val;
}
```

Here is how I try to use it

```
Dictionary<string,object> dictionary = <stuff>
object val = dictionary.ObjectForKey("some string");
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not getting this error here. Please provide more context, or try reducing the use case to its minimum, maybe as a new project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define your extension method inside of a **static** (to make is extension) and **public** (to make it accessible outside of the class) class

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static TValue ObjectForKey<TKey,TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey,TValue> dictionary, TKey key)
    {
        TValue val = default(TValue);
        dictionary.TryGetValue(key,out val);
        return val;
    }
}
```

Comment: ...and make sure the namespace is included in your `using` statements if it isn't the same as the class where the extension is being used.

Comment: @Selman22 It would not compile if that was not already the case.

Comment: They might have defined the extension inside another instance class. It would compile but it wouldn't be detected as a proper extension method when it came to invoke it, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Ok it was there, but not static. Thanks! Problem solved. Ill mark soon as its able.

Comment: Actually, when I try to define an extension method inside an instance class, I get a compile error "Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class"